# Spring extensions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

> A certain spring has attached to it a mass of 25 units: on increasing the load by 6 units it extends 2.5 cm.
>
> a) What is the time of oscillation under the original load?
>
> b) What will be the velocity and acceleration when it is midway between its lowest and mean positions if it is loaded as at first, pulled down 5 cm and let go?

I am guessing the spring is hung vertically. Do I work out the modulus of elasticity first? I guess the equations $\omega=\sqrt{k/m}$ will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use SI units so mass is in kilograms and length is in meters.  Let the original mass be $m_1 = 25 \,\mathrm{kg}$ and the final mass be $m_2 = m_1 +\Delta m$ where $\Delta m = 6 \,\mathrm{kg}$.  Let the original extension of the spring be $x_1$ and the final extension be $x_1 + \Delta x_1$ where $\Delta x = 2.5\, \mathrm{cm}$.  We can determine the spring constant by noting that in each case, the gravitational force of the mass on the spring must balance the spring force pulling up; this gives two equations:

$m_1g = k(x_1 - x_\mathrm{eq})$

$m_2g = k(x_2 - x_\mathrm{eq})$

so that subtracting the first equation from the second gives

$(m_2 - m_1)g = k(x_2-x_1)$

which given the notation above gives

$\Delta m g = k \Delta x$

so the spring constant is

$ k = \frac{\Delta m}{\Delta x} g = \frac{6\,\mathrm{kg}}{2.5\,\mathrm{cm}} g$

With this in hand, you can indeed compute the angular frequency for the original load $m_1$ using the formula you wrote.  This in turn will give you the period, which is what I assume part (a) is asking for.  I'll let you think about part (b) since this sounds like a homework question to me.

Let me know of any typos.

Cheers!

Comment: Just remember not to give away too much when you're answering a homework question ;-)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Yea; my apologies.  I'll make my comments more general next time.

Comment: So the time period is

$\omega = \sqrt{k/m_1}=\sqrt{12/(5gm_1)}
2\pi f=\sqrt{12/5gm_1}
T=2\pi \sqrt{5gm_1/12}$